# script to compress user files via searching through folders for certain folder name

Tags: bash, shell, loops, scripting

I'm writing a function for one of my programs that will need to search through a number of folders until we find a folder called "userfiles" then we tar up this folder giving the filename of the folder it was found in. Is the below approach the best way to go?

```
compress(){
NAME=$(cat $USER_HOME/server.txt | sed -e "s/ //g")
USERS=/var/www/home/user/area/*/*/*/
IDS=${PWD##*/}

# Apache Logs
tar -zcvf logs-$NAME.tar.gz /var/log/apache2

# User Logs
 for i in $USERS; 
       do
               if [ ! -d "userfiles" ];
                       then
                               tar -zcvf userfiles-$NAME-"$IDS".tar.gz  $USERS
               fi
 done;

# Linux Logs
tar -zcvf linux-logs-$NAME.tar.gz /var/log/auth.log* /var/log/syslog* /var/log/kern.log* /var/log/mail.log*


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
for i in $USERS; 
  do
    if [ ! -d "userfiles" ];
      then
        tar -zcvf userfiles-$NAME-"$IDS".tar.gz  $USERS
    fi
done;
```

won't do what you described it should do. Instead, if a folder `userfiles` does **not** exist in the **current working directory**, it will tar **all** user folders multiple times.

Try something like this:

```
for d in $USERS; do
  if [ -d "${d}userfiles" ]; then
    tar -zcvf "userfiles-$NAME-$IDS.tar.gz" "${d}userfiles"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks its works - the $IDS aren't getting put into the filename and only the last dir is added to the zip. As a work around I've removed $IDS and added the tar to 'r' to append the tar

Answer (score 0):

I'd save a useless use of cat with

```
 NAME=$(sed -e "s/ //g" $USER_HOME/server.txt)
```

It also looks like you never use `$USERS` and `$IDS` in the function.

Comment: Assuming the `sed` command is only used to remove leading or trailing space, `NAME=( $(< $USER_HOME/server.txt) )` is a slightly convoluted way to achieving the same without spawning an external processes.

Comment: Thanks for the cat tip - I've un-hashed the rest of the script which I didn't before

Answer (score 0):

There are several things in this script that will not work, and I'm not sure I found them all:

1. Do you really want to check *all* directories that are *exactly* 3 levels below `/var/www/home/user/area/`? I'd expect either something more restrictive (that is, only within subdirectories that carry certain names) or something more permissive (that is, all directories at most 3 levels below `/var/www/home/user/area/`).
2. The `for` loop uses a variable `i`, but `i` isn't used anywhere in the body of the loop. That can't work.
3. The test `if [ ! -d "userfiles" ]` is executed always in the same (i.e., the current) directory. That can't work either.
4. I don't understand the negation in `if [ ! -d "userfiles" ]`.
5. The argument of `tar` is `$USERS`. I'd expect something like `"$i/userfiles"`.